# Ordering in selection result. Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Does the sequence of records in SELECT QUERY in result always the same?
I mean that if the first result of operation returns the following sequence:
first record 
second record
third record 
All other select * from t queries always return records in the same sequence.

Comment: No, that's not guaranteed unless you use `ORDER BY` to explicitly sort the result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A SQL query -- like a SQL table -- represents an *unordered* set.  There is no ordering, unless an `ORDER BY` is present for the outermost `SELECT`.

As an unordered set, the same query can return results in a different order each time it is run.

So, if you want results in a particular order, use `ORDER BY`.

I should add that if multiple rows have the same key, then these rows can appear in any order, even with an `ORDER BY`.  In general, you should ensure that the keys in the `ORDER BY` uniquely define each row (say by including the primary key as the final key).